# SAS: PROC SQL Table gets bigger and bigger

Tags: sql, sas, dataset, proc

I am using proc sql to (see code below) to generate a table fro ma view that I created before. If I run it, the sql step starts and doesn't stop until my hard drive is full (2TB). I don't know what's happening as the few included tables are a max. size of 3GB with 8 columns, no massive calculations are done.

```
proc sql; create table study3 as select a.*,b.news 
    from study2 a,gb_news b where a.ann_date=b.ann_date 
    order by a.symbol,a.ann_date,a.event_time;                                  
quit;
```

Thankful for any help!

Comment: do you really need all the fields by using *?

Comment: Do your source tables have only one observations per ANN_DATE? If not then you are multiplying your number of records. Say on average each date has 100 observations in both files. Then in the new file you will have 100*100 observations per date.

Comment: Yes I think that's the case. I have several hundred ann_dates. I don't see that it multiplies and makes >2TB out of 3GB. But yeah, obviously it does. Thanks!!